# Как выводить информацию с поля foreignkey через serilazer?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Мои модели:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='owner')
    allowed_users = models.ManyToManyField(User)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Lesson(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    link = models.URLField()
    time = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    products = models.ManyToManyField(Product)


def __str__(self):
    return self.name


class UserLessons(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    lesson = models.ForeignKey(Lesson, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    is_view = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    view_time = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    date_view = models.DateField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} - {self.lesson.name}'
```

serilazer:

```
class UserLessonsSerializerV1(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserLessons
        fields = ['lesson', 'is_view', 'view_time']
```

Возможно ли обращаться к `lesson`, чтобы выводить из нее данные?
Пытался через `lesson__name`, но не получилось.